# Best practice(s) for on screen real-time log viewer for log4net

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

I have a multi-threaded C# application that use log4net for logging capabilities. Mainly the RollingFileAppender.

I want to offer the capability for the user to view the activity of the application in an "application log" window. This will consist of a listview (details mode), a grid or something similar.

I'm looking for best ways to do it. The only solution I have so far is to setup an UDP appender and create a special thread that will listen and foward all messages to the UI.

I also examined the possibility to create a "wrapper" that both write to the UI, the log the message using log4net... hum.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Answer (score 7):

If you're happy to rely on another program you can use [dbgview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) from Sysinternals. This will display anything that is logged with [Debug.WriteLine()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline.aspx) method. I think that the [OutputDebugStringAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.OutputDebugStringAppender.html) will do this, but I've not used Log4Net so I can't be sure.

Comment: You can also send log4net to trace output.

Answer (score 2):

Do you require viewing the persisted log data in this window? If so, I would recommend logging to a database. Then log4net can work undisturbed by the client which can read the log data from the database in a non-locking manner.

You could use SQL Server Compact edition if you don't want/have an Express or full server going.

Logging to database is done with the built-in log4net [AdoNetAdapter](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Peter Lillevold. Here is a simple example of how to log to a db from a console app by dynamically setting the verbosity of the logging

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using log4net;
using log4net.Config;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace ExampleConsoleApplication
{
    [TestFixture]
    class TestClass
    {

    //private static readonly ILog logger =
    //     LogManager.GetLogger ( typeof ( TestClass ) );

    private static readonly log4net.ILog logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger ( System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod ().DeclaringType );

        static void Main ( string[] args )
        {

            Console.WriteLine ( " START " );
            #region LoggerUsage
            DOMConfigurator.Configure (); //tis configures the logger 
            logger.Debug ( "Here is a debug log." );
            logger.Info ( "... and an Info log." );
            logger.Warn ( "... and a warning." );
            logger.Error ( "... and an error." );
            logger.Fatal ( "... and a fatal error." );

            #endregion LoggerUsage
            TestClass objTestClass = new TestClass();
            objTestClass.TestMethodNameOK ();
            objTestClass.TestMethodNameNOK ();

            Console.WriteLine ( " END HIT A KEY TO EXIT " );
            Console.ReadLine ();
            } //eof method 

        [SetUp]
        protected void SetUp ()
        {
            //Add Here the Initialization of the objects 
        }
        [Test ( Description = "Add here the description of this test method " )]
        protected void TestMethodNameOK ()
        { 
            //build ok use case scenario here - e.g. no exception should be raced '
            //Vegetable newCarrot = pool.GetItemByPropertyValue<Vegetable> ( "WriongByPurpose", "Orange" );
            //Assert.IsInstanceOfType ( typeof ( Vegetable ), newCarrot );
            //Assert.AreSame ( newCarrot, carrot );
            //logger.Info ( " I got the newCarrot which is " + newCarrot.Color );

        } //eof method 

        [Test ( Description = "Add here the description of this test method " )]
        protected void TestMethodNameNOK ()         //e.g. the one that should raze Exception
        {
            //build ok use case scenario here - e.g. no exception should be raced '
            //Vegetable newCarrot = pool.GetItemByPropertyValue<Vegetable> ( "WriongByPurpose", "Orange" );
            //Assert.IsInstanceOfType ( typeof ( Vegetable ), newCarrot );
            //Assert.AreSame ( newCarrot, carrot );
            //logger.Info ( " I got the newCarrot which is " + newCarrot.Color );

        } //eof method 

    } //eof class 

} //eof namespace 





#region TheAppConfig
/*
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net"
                 type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
    </configSections>

    <log4net>
        <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
            <param name="File" value="Program.log" />
            <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <!--<param name="Header" value="======================================" />
        <param name="Footer" value="======================================" />-->
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p - %m%n" />
      </layout>
        </appender>

        <appender name="ColoredConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender">
      <mapping>
        <level value="ERROR" />
        <foreColor value="Red" />
      </mapping>
      <mapping>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <foreColor value="HighIntensity" />
      </mapping>
      <mapping>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <foreColor value="Green" />
      </mapping>
      <mapping>
        <level value="WARN" />
        <foreColor value="Yellow" />
      </mapping>
      <mapping>
        <level value="FATAL" />
        <foreColor value="White" />
        <backColor value="Red" />
      </mapping>

      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
            </layout>
        </appender>


        <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
            <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
            <connectionString value="data source=ysg;initial catalog=DBGA_DEV;integrated security=true;persist security info=True;" />
            <commandText value="INSERT INTO [DBGA_DEV].[ga].[tb_Data_Log] ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message)" />

            <parameter>
                <parameterName value="@log_date" />
                <dbType value="DateTime" />
                <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%date{yyyy'.'MM'.'dd HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff}" />
            </parameter>
            <parameter>
                <parameterName value="@thread" />
                <dbType value="String" />
                <size value="255" />
                <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%thread" />
            </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@domainName" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%user" />
      </parameter>
            <parameter>
                <parameterName value="@log_level" />
                <dbType value="String" />
                <size value="50" />
                <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%level" />
            </parameter>
            <parameter>
                <parameterName value="@logger" />
                <dbType value="String" />
                <size value="255" />
                <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%logger" />
            </parameter>
            <parameter>
                <parameterName value="@message" />
                <dbType value="String" />
                <size value="4000" />
                <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%message" />
            </parameter>
        </appender>
        <root>
            <level value="ALL" />
            <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
            <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
            <appender-ref ref="ColoredConsoleAppender" />
        </root>
    </log4net>
</configuration>
*/
#endregion TheAppconfig

 //this is the xml added replace here your log4net and Nunit paths
//<Reference Include="log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
        //  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
        //  <HintPath>..\..\..\Log4Net\log4net-1.2.10\bin\net\2.0\release\log4net.dll</HintPath>
        //</Reference>
        //<Reference Include="nunit.framework, Version=2.4.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
```

Answer (score 0):

What about writing your own appender that will fire an event when something happens? You can obtain it's instance by examining log4net repository.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the log4net viewer. See Ayende's blog post [Watching the logs run with log4net](https://ayende.com/blog/1634/watching-the-logs-run-with-log4net).